# Jackson to parse complex objects

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I want to parse json object using jackson. My object structure is something like:
LiveShow.java:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class LiveShow implements Serializable{

    @JsonProperty("showid")
    public String showid;
    @JsonProperty("time")
    public String time;
    @JsonProperty("provider")
    public int provider;
    @JsonProperty("sponser")
    public String sponser;


    @JsonCreator
    public LiveShow(@JsonProperty("showid") String showid, 
            @JsonProperty("time") String time,
            @JsonProperty("provider") int provider,
            @JsonProperty("sponser") String sponser) {
        super();
        this.showid= showid;
        this.time = time;
        this.provider = provider;
        this.sponser = sponser;
    } 

    public String getShowid() {
        return showid;
    }

    public void setTopid(String showid) {
        this.showid = showid;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public int getProvider() {
        return provider;
    }

    public void setProvider(int provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public String getSponser() {
        return sponser;
    }

    public void setSponser(String sponser) {
        this.sponser = sponser;
    }
}
```

MonthlyShows.java:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
//@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class MonthlyShows implements Serializable{
    @JsonProperty("live_shows")
    public LiveShow[] live_shows;
    @JsonProperty("month")
    public String month;
    @JsonCreator
    public MonthlyShows(@JsonProperty("live_shows") LiveShow[] live_shows, 
            @JsonProperty("month") String month) {
        super();
        setLive_shows(live_shows);
        setMonth(month);
    }

    public LiveShow[] getLive_shows() {
        return live_shows;
    }

    public void setLive_shows(LiveShow[] live_shows) {
        try{
            this.live_shows = new LiveShow[live_shows.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < live_shows.length; i++)
                this.live_shows[i] = live_shows[i];
            }catch(Exception e){

                System.err.println("live_shows is null");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public String getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(String month) {
        this.month = month;
    }
}
```

How I parse the object:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MonthlyShows showsInApril = mapper.readValue(jsonString, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(MonthlyShows.class));
System.out.println("month:" + showsInApril.month);
for(LiveShow s : showsInApril.live_shows)
    System.out.println(s.showid+ "\t" + s.time + "\t" + s.provider);
```

I'm getting null pointer exception which I understood to mean that I can't parse such compound/complex object.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MonthlyShows.setLive_shows(MonthlyShows.java:49)
    at MonthlyShows.<init>(LiveRelevanceJudgments.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedConstructor.call(AnnotatedConstructor.java:114)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromObjectWith(StdValueInstantiator.java:256)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.PropertyBasedCreator.build(PropertyBasedCreator.java:135)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:444)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1123)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:298)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:133)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2817)
    at Test.main(Test.java:189)
```

month: April

Is there a way to work around the problem?

### **EDIT:**

example of json object I'm parsing is:

```
{
    "live_shows":[
        {"showid":"show1","time":"02216629","provider":0,"sponser":"governmental"},
        {"showid":"show2","time":"00050340","provider":2,"sponser":"business"}
    ],
    "month":"April"
}
```

And I fixed the types of attributes as pointed by Nico in the comments below.
+ provided the full classes as requested

Comment: Could you show the JSON you are sending to reproduce this error?

Comment: You are sending the long value for time as a string.

Comment: kindly format your code and json for better readability. Its better you include entire MonthlyShows class as that is where NPE is thrown

Comment: Do you have getter and setters in these classes? if not, try after writing getters and setters for all properties and accessing variables via them.

Comment: @Nikhil Sahu thanks for the suggestion. I added getters and setter and edited the question accordingly. Still have the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json string is the wrong format. You declare time as long type, but you send a String value.
Just a little note with a numeric value, A leading zero is not allowed.
For example: "time": 02216629 is wrong. Correctly value is: 22166299

Sometime I want to see a json clearly. I'll create a sample object and print as json value. For example:
You can do that too using ObjectMapper.

For example:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.valueToTree(monthlyShows);
```

Then get a validated json

```
{"live_shows":[{"showid":"s101","time":1500624568893,"provider":1,"sponser":"ABC sponser"}],"month":"July"}
```

Comment: As Nico pointed above, I modified the class LiveShow.java itself and changed the time from long to String as this json object is retrieved from end point API. Thanks. Can you show me how to use jsonNode in my context please?

Comment: oh, very simple. Just create a MonthlyShows object and convert object to JsonNode as my code above, then print as String use System.out or logger.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @PhongTn. For some reason, it didn't work, I'm still getting the null pointer exception reported above

Comment: Hmm. Just write a sample using your code, and everything seems ok.    
The repository is on  [GitHub](https://github.com/phongtn/SampleJsonParse.git)            
How do you get the "jsonString"? Where your input, from a file or stream?  
I think may be "jsonString" is not well formed after parsed from an input.

Comment: It's from end point api; I issue a http request and I get it. But now for testing purposes, I'm reading it from a file. I wrote this file from a response of old http request I issued.

Comment: Hmm, are you check my sample?. Just updated a method reading from a file and everything ok.  You can check on [GitHub](https://github.com/phongtn/SampleJsonParse).  I was usually working on RESTful project processing JSON data from HTTP request.  So, I can write a sample with HTTP endpoint if you want.   
Also, can you upload your project?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` to avoid deserialization of null attributes:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class MonthlyShows {

  @JsonProperty("live_shows")
  public LiveShow[] live_shows;
  ...
}
```

and change your `MonthlyShows` constructor this way:

```
@JsonCreator
public MonthlyShows(@JsonProperty("live_shows") LiveShow[] live_shows, 
@JsonProperty("month") String month) {
  super();
  this.live_shows = live_shows;
  this.month = month;
}
```

Here is full code sample:

```
public class DeserializationTests {

private ObjectMapper mapper;

@Before
public void setUp() {
mapper = new ObjectMapper();
}

@Test
public void deserializeFullMonthlyShows() throws Exception {
String jsonString = "{\"live_shows\":[{\"showid\":\"showid1\",\"time\":14000000000,\"provider\":1,\"sponser\":\"sponser1\"},{\"showid\":\"showid2\",\"time\":15000000000,\"provider\":2,\"sponser\":\"sponser2\"}],\"month\": \"April\"}";
MonthlyShows showsInApril = mapper.readValue(jsonString, MonthlyShows.class);
printOutMonthlyShows(showsInApril);
}

@Test
public void deserializeEmptyMonthlyShows() throws Exception {
String jsonString = "{\"live_shows\":[],\"month\": \"April\"}";
MonthlyShows showsInApril = mapper.readValue(jsonString, MonthlyShows.class);
printOutMonthlyShows(showsInApril);
}

@Test
public void deserializeNoShows() throws Exception {
String jsonString = "{\"month\": \"April\"}";
MonthlyShows showsInApril = mapper.readValue(jsonString, MonthlyShows.class);
System.out.println("month:" + showsInApril.month);
Assert.assertNull(showsInApril.live_shows);
}

@Test
public void deserializeWrongMonthlyShows() throws Exception {
String jsonString = "{\"live_shows\":[{\"showid\":\"showid1\",\"time\":\"14000000000\",\"provider\":1,\"sponser\":\"sponser1\"},{\"showid\":\"showid2\",\"time\":\"15000000000\",\"provider\":2,\"sponser\":\"sponser2\"}],\"month\": \"April\"}";
MonthlyShows showsInApril = mapper.readValue(jsonString, MonthlyShows.class);
printOutMonthlyShows(showsInApril);
}

@Test
public void deserializeTheJsonYouProvide() throws Exception {
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString = "{\"live_shows\":[{\"showid\":\"show1\",\"time\":\"02216629\",\"provider\":0,\"sponser\":\"governmental\"},{\"showid\":\"show2\",\"time\":\"00050340\",\"provider\":2,\"sponser\":\"business\"}],\"month\":\"April\"}";
MonthlyShows showsInApril = mapper.readValue(jsonString, MonthlyShows.class);
printOutMonthlyShows(showsInApril);
}

private void printOutMonthlyShows(MonthlyShows showsInApril) {
System.out.println("month:" + showsInApril.month);
for (LiveShow s : showsInApril.live_shows)
    System.out.println(s.showid + "\t" + s.time + "\t" + s.provider);
}
}
```

And here is a snippet of my pom.xml:

```
...
<properties>
    <jackson.version>2.8.6</jackson.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

Comment: this is really helpful when the live_shows array is null, but what I'm parsing is not a null array. Thanks for providing example code. However, my problem is that: the array contains Liveshow objects and I'm getting null pointer exception!

Comment: I used your test example, in my project and I still get error. Did you really try it? this will be strange.

Comment: what version of Jackson are you using?

Comment: @sareem 2.8.6. I update my answer with a snippet of my pom.